# Different versions of Eclipse plugin BIRT

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, version, birt

What are the main differences between BIRT tool version 2.6 and 3.7 ?

Are there any particular requirements that version 3.7 demands for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some changes. See [New and Notable Features within BIRT 3.7](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/project/notable3.7.php).

I expecially noticed the new structure of the runtime environment: forget the old and weird *platform* folder, now it's all organized in JARs, inside *WEB-INF/lib*, as it would be expected. Now, for example, there's no need to indicate where the platform is with `config.setBIRTHome("pathtoruntime");`.